# Function in PostgreSQL to execute the same code block to different tables

Tags: postgresql, function

Say I have the following request :

```
WITH table_1 AS (
.....
)
SELECT 
  DATE(ts) AS day,
  COUNT(*) AS nb_1
  clients AS clients_1
FROM table_1
WHERE location IN ('USA', 'SPAIN')
GROUP BY day
```

I want to apply the exact same SELECT command to table_1, but also to many other tables table_2, table_3, .... table_N, that I am also creating with a WITH statement. Also I am applying the requests to a ***read-only*** instance.

Is it possible to wrap up the command that I want to repeat so that I don't repeat the whole block N times ? Is a function suitable knowing that I am requesting a read-only instance ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the instance is read-only as long as you issue a `SELECT` statement only. As for the question, you can write a function that runs dynamic SQL but it's a bit ugly solution. If the tables are of the same structure you can use UNION to query them N times. Also you can use tools like **dbt** to build SQL dynamically based on the list of the tables.

Comment: I wrote a function with `CREATE FUNCTION` and I get : `cannot execute CREATE FUNCTION in a read-only transaction`. This is in line with [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: ah you're right, you can't create an object... then your only options are unions or some external tool like `dbt` that can generate the dynamic sql for you. Or if you know some scripting language you can generate it yourself